# Change column format ( Custom -> DATE )

Tags: excel, xlsxwriter

I am currently having issues exporting a dataframe to excel ( using python / pandas / xlsxwriter ). I tried exporting the column "date" as datetime or string, and both give me the same result ( in the end the cells are "Custom" in XL... ) . Visually it's fine, they all look "0k":
[image]

But then I need to import this into another program and it's giving errors.... I could fix this issue by changing by hand the format of the cells, from " Custom" to " Date "
And manually I'm changing the format as following:
[image]

and I was trying to do this with Powershell ( any other option would be fine as well ), but currently I have reached some dead ends..... 
Appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: How were you doing pandas/python with PowerShell?  Can you show some code that you tried and what errors you encountered?

Comment: I don't have errors, but SAS is still reading these fields as " number " or general.... 
For example :18-3-2019 becomes 43542

But if I change the format of the cells by hand into date, it works....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number formats created with XlsxWriter will show up as a category such as Number, Date, Time, Currency, Accountancy, etc. if they match a format used by Excel for that category. Otherwise it will show up as a "Custom" format.

Here is an example that demonstrates the difference:

```
from datetime import datetime
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('datetimes.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Expand the first columns so that the dates are visible.
worksheet.set_column('A:B', 30)

# Create a datetime object to use in the examples.
date_time = datetime.strptime('2019-01-23 12:30:05.123',
                              '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
# Create some date formats.
date_format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy'})
date_format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy'})

# Write the same date using different formats.
worksheet.write_datetime(0, 0, date_time, date_format1)
worksheet.write_datetime(1, 0, date_time, date_format2)

workbook.close()
```

The date in cell A1 shows up as "Custom". The date in cell A2 shows up as "Date":

[image]

You can find the correct format string by setting the Excel format category for a cell, and then in the Number dialog scrolling down to see what it is in the "Custom" category:

[image]

In Pandas you can set the date/datetime format strings as shown in the XlsxWriter docs on [Formatting of the Dataframe output](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-output).

It should be noted that this can be slightly dependent on the Excel version or locale. For example the code above should, but may not, produce the same result in versions of Excel/Windows with different default number/date formats.

**Update**: See the updated XlsxWriter docs on how to get [Number Format Categories](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#number-format-categories).

Comment: Yes, I am currently using : 

" df_tst['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_tst['date'] , format='%Y-%m-%d') "
and...
" writer = pd.ExcelWriter(mutaties_path , engine='xlsxwriter' , datetime_format='yyyy-mm-dd' ) "

I also saw that ( about the Custom format ), that's why I was trying to format the cell either with a macro or with powershell.... Because the problem is that this goes as input for another program, and if I don't change the format by hand to "date" 

It reads as " number " or " general ", for example : 
 18-3-2019 becomes 43542

Comment: Formatting the dates in the DataFrame is not the same as formatting them in Excel. If you need the format to show up as “Date” instead of “Custom” then you can follow the steps I laid out above. Then you shouldn’t need to use macros or Powershell.

Comment: Indeed... thanks for the help!
I am using the " ... engine='xlsxwriter' , datetime_format='dd-mm-yyyy' "  and I do an extra formatting step when loading the sheets into the other program...

Comment: And does `dd-mm-yyyy` correspond to one of the inbuilt "Date" formats in your version of Excel?

Comment: This dosen't work. Both show up as custom for me.

Comment: See the updated docs in the link above.